# Assembly 8x8 four quadrant multiply algorithm

Tags: math, assembly, binary, multiplication, avr

In the book "Musical Applications of Microprocessors," the author gives the following algorithm to do a 4 quadrant multiplication of two 8 bit signed integers with a 16 bit signed result:

Do an unsigned multiply on the raw operands.  Then to correct the result, if the multiplicand sign is negative, unsigned single precision subtract the multiplier from the top 8 bits of the raw 16 bit result.  If the multiplier sign is also negative, unsigned single precision subtract the multiplicand from the top 8 bits of the raw 16 bit result.

I tried implementing this in assembler and can't seem to get it to work.  For example, if I unsigned multiply -2 times -2 the raw result in binary is B11111100.00000100.  When I subtract B1111110 twice from the top 8 bits according to the algorithm, I get B11111110.00000100, not B00000000.00000100 as one would want.  Thanks for any insight into where I might be going wrong!

Edit - code:

```
    #define smultfix(a,b)       \
    ({                      \
    int16_t sproduct;               \
    int8_t smultiplier = a, smultiplicand = b;  \
    uint16_t uproduct = umultfix(smultiplier,smultiplicand);\
    asm volatile (                  \
    "add %2, r1 \n\t"               \
    "brpl smult_"QUOTE(__LINE__)"\n\t"      \
    "sec                 \n\t"      \
    "sbc  %B3, %1            \n\t"      \
    "smult_"QUOTE(__LINE__)": add %1, r1 \n\t"  \
    "brpl send_"QUOTE(__LINE__)"  \n\t"     \
    "sec                 \n\t"      \
    "sbc  %B3, %2            \n\t"      \
    "send_"QUOTE(__LINE__)": movw %A0,%A3 \n\t" \
    :"=&r" (sproduct):"a" (smultiplier), "a" (smultiplicand), "a" (uproduct)\
    );                      \
    sproduct;                   \
    })
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post some code?

Comment: The code is in AVR-GCC inline assembler so it's _really_ ugly.  I can certainly post it if it might help though...

Comment: Just saying it might be easier to help if we saw some code. :) (unless its 400 lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:
You got the subtraction wrong.

```
1111'1110b * 1111'1110b == 1111'1100'0000'0100b
                          -1111'1110'0000'0000b                   
                          -1111'1110'0000'0000b  
                          ---------------------
                                           100b
```

Otherwise your algorithm is correct: In the fourth quadrant, you need to subtract 100h multiplied with the sum (a+b). Writing the two-complement bytes as (100h-x) I get:

```
(100h-a)(100h-b) = 10000h - 100h*(a+b) + ab = 100h*(100h-a) + 100h*(100h-b) + ab mod 10000h
(100h-a)(100h-b) - 100h*(100h-a) - 100*(100h-b) = ab mod 10000h
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I subtract B1111110 twice from
>   the top 8 bits according to the
>   algorithm, I get B11111110.00000100,
>   not B00000000.00000100 as one would
>   want.

If I subtract `B11111110` twice from `B11111100`, I get `B00000000`, as required:

```
B11111100 - B11111110 = B11111110
B11111110 - B11111110 = B00000000
```

Seems simple enough.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is the output of the program where the subtraction is producing the incorrect results.  I'm not great at AVR assembly, I'll have to look more carefully at what's going on with those subtract commands in the disassembler.